# 'S2Quickstart' not found - what files does it generate or edit?

Tags: grails

with grails 2.3.6, and no other plugins installed, I followed the official documentation and edited BuildConfig.groovy:

```
    compile: ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
```

under plugins and

```
    mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
```

under repositories.

Then did 
    "grails compile"  (also tried doing a "grails clean" first)

and always get: "compiling 1 source files."

But when I run:

```
grails s2-quickstart com.mydom User Role
```

I always get:

```
Script 'S2Quickstart' not found When adding Spring security plugin
```

Having spent days trying to fix, I have now given up, and instead would like to get hold of the files that the script would have created or edited. Could someone run this command for me, and upload, or paste in, the results?

Comment: `compile: ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"` should be under plugins instead of dependencies in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Comment: Sorry, i have it in plugins, and doesnt work. I tried various other compbinations in despiration

Comment: Minute detail I missed as well. I copied from the question without knowing there is a colon after compile. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the error.  The tutorial I cut and paste it from had a superfluous colon, so it was:

```
    compile: ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
```

When it should be:

```
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
```

Unfortunately, this does not generate any warnings or errors.

Comment: You should accept this answer so others don't try to help

Comment: it does not complain as this is valid groovy.  it creates a new map. ``print compile: ":..."``

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before i can accept it as an answer :(